# retrieving data using prepared statements in C#

Tags: c#, prepared-statement

i have a table with 3 columns(EmpId,EmpName,EmpSalary).
i am using a prepared statement to retrieve all the data from this table using prepared statement.
here is what i have written...

```
try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmpId,EmpName,EmpSalary FROM EmpDetails";

            SqlParameter paraId = new SqlParameter();
            paraId.ParameterName = "@id";
            paraId.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            paraId.Size = 32;


            SqlParameter paraName = new SqlParameter();
            paraName.ParameterName = "@name";
            paraName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            paraName.Size = 50;

            SqlParameter paraSal = new SqlParameter();
            paraSal.ParameterName = "@sal";
            paraSal.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
            paraSal.Precision = 7;
            paraSal.Scale = 2;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(paraId);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paraName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paraSal);

            con.Open();
            cmd.Prepare();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string str = "";
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                string id = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                string name = dr.GetString(1);
                string sal = dr.IsDBNull(2) ? "is null" : dr.GetDecimal(2).ToString();
                str += id + "\t" + name + "\t" + sal + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(str);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
```

but i am getting an error as follows :
"The parameterized Query expects the parameter @id , which was not supplied."

What mistake am i doing here..??

Comment: Why do you need to add the parameters if your query does not have a where clause? The error you see is because, You are just adding the parameters but not supplying any values.

Comment: The error probably says he is using a `where` clause, which he forgot to mention perhaps. @ryadavilli

Comment: Probably, in any case, the error is because of missing values in the parameters like you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @ryadavilli 
i need to use the prepared statement to retrieve all data.
Please tell me what changes should i make..

Answer (score 1):

Please use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()`. Using `cmd.Parameters.Add()` is deprecated. Google its uses :-)

Comment: got all confused and messed up everything.
Can you just show me how to retrieve data using PREPARED STATEMENT..??

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, you will need to supply parameters value like below.

```
        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmpId,EmpName,EmpSalary FROM EmpDetails ";

            SqlParameter paraId = new SqlParameter();
            paraId.ParameterName = "@id";
            paraId.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            paraId.Size = 32;


            SqlParameter paraName = new SqlParameter();
            paraName.ParameterName = "@name";
            paraName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            paraName.Size = 50;

            SqlParameter paraSal = new SqlParameter();
            paraSal.ParameterName = "@sal";
            paraSal.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
            paraSal.Precision = 7;
            paraSal.Scale = 2;

            //i assume you forgot to setup parameter values.

            paraId.Value = 1;
            paraName.Value = "thisName";
            paraSal.Value = 343;


            cmd.Parameters.Add(paraId);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paraName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paraSal);

            con.Open();
            cmd.Prepare();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string str = "";
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string id = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                string name = dr.GetString(1);
                string sal = dr.IsDBNull(2) ? "is null" : dr.GetDecimal(2).ToString();
                str += id + "\t" + name + "\t" + sal + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(str);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
```